# Get all form fields from form and save them in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

On form submission I want to get all form fields and save them in an array. But there are few textboxes, select boxes, input fields, check boxes and radio buttons. This is a dynamic form built in WordPress and user can change these fields from back end.
Here is my code

```
var form_label = [];
var form_value = [];
i = 0;
jQuery('#form6 .wdform-field').each(
    function (index) {
        var form_label[i++] = jQuery(this).find(label).text();
        var form_value[i++] = jQuery(this).find(input).val();
    }
);
```

There is a `div` with class `wdform-field` outside of each form fields but i do not know this field will be an input field, a checkbox or text area. Right now as mention in above code it is working fine for only input fields but it is not working for other form fields like text area or checkbox. So in this case how I can get these values and their labels properly form all form fields. 
Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Okay but my question is about getting these values from form fields. As i mention there will be some textboxes, checkboxes, input fields. So how i can get these values dynamically and store these in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be i was not able to explain my question very well. But this code is working for me.

```
<script>
var form_label = new Array();
var form_value = new Array();

jQuery('#form6 .wdform-field').each(
    function(index){
    form_label.push(jQuery(this).find('label').text());
    form_value.push(jQuery(this).find(':input').val());
}
);
</script>
```

With this code i am able to get value from all form fields `.find(':input')`
and values are also saving correctly in array now.

Answer (score 0):

Use SerializeArray(), to get form fields in array

```
jQuery(form.event).serializeArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add attribute "name" to input, button, checkbox, radio, text area ...etc

And use serialize to get form fields

More info https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in other answers form inputs can be captured by Serialize/SerializeArray from Jquery.

```js
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {

  document.write(JSON.stringify($( this ).serializeArray()));
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<form name="tstForm">
<input type="text" value="Jor" name="txtName" />
<input type="text" value="Dar" name="txtLastName" />
<select name="Qual">
 <option>A</option>
 <option>B</option>
 <option>C</option>
 <input type="submit" />
</select>
</form>
</div>
```